# C++ template specialization with any non-type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I want to specialize a template. The specialization takes as one type another template, which has a non-type template parameter. I want the specialization to apply for any value of the non-type parameter. I can specialize for a specific non-type value, but I don't know how to do it in general.

For example:

```
template<typename T, int N>   // first definition
struct A;

template<typename T>          // second definition
struct B;

template<>                    // this compiles, N is fixed
struct B<A<float,1>>;

template<>              // For general N this doesn't compile, says
struct B<A<float,int>>;  // "expected a constant of type ‘int’, got ‘int’"
```

Is there a way to accomplish it, so that I have a specialization of B if the parameter is A, no matter what the value of int N for A was?

Comment: I wrote an answer. If you found it useful please consider voting/accepting it! (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because you are passing the type int as a template parameter, where you need an integer value. To allow for any integer value as a parameter you should write something like

```
template<int P> // For any int value P
struct B<A<float,P>>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
template<> 
struct B<A<float,int>>;
```

use

```
template<int N> 
struct B<A<float, N>>;
```

The first one does not work since `A` requires a type and an `int`, not two types.

> I want the specialization to apply for any value of the non-type parameter.

My suggestion will indeed do that.

```
B<A<float, 1>> b1;     // Uses the specialization
B<A<float, 200>> b2;   // Also uses the specialization
```

Answer (score 0):

Specializing like:

```
template<>
struct B<A<float,int>>{...};
```

Is not correct since  the declaration `template<typename T, int N> struct A;` states that N is the template non-type/non-template  parameter of type `int` for the class template. And it can not be substituted by a type (in this case `int`).

In this case one should exclusively provide a value parameter instead and since it is desired to have the specialization for any value but only one type (`float` in the following examples), First a representation for the value as a generic case should appear in `template< ___ >` so then it can be used to define the term `B< _____ >`.

there are 2 options in this case like:

```
template<int N>
struct B<A<float,N>>{...};
```

Or like:

```
template<auto N>
struct B<A<float,N>>{...};
```

In both case compiler prepares to look for a value to substitute for `N` as the template non-type/non-template parameter.

Finally class template `B` can be used like:

```
B<A<float, 666> > possessed_object;
```

Please also note that if type of `N` was different from `int` , for example if it was `size_t`, when using the second option (the one with `auto`) like:

```
template<typename T, size_t N> 
struct A{...};
template<auto N>
struct B<A<float,N>>{...};
```

then (assured) usage becomes like:

```
B<A<float, size_t(666)> > possessed_object;
```

Although in some implementations it might not matter and the first mentioned usage may still be OK to use.

Good luck!

Comment: Please note that ```template<>struct B<A<float,1>>;``` is not the actual specialization (but just another declaration) until you provide the definition ```template<>struct B<A<float,1>>{...};```